# Problem with template (unresolved overloaded function type)

Tags: c++, templates

The following code fail to compile because function `g` but I don't know why.

```
template <int N>
struct  A{
    template <int n>
    int f() {return n;}
};

template <int N>
int g(A<N>& a)
{
    return a.f<10>();
}

int main()
{
   A<1> a;
   g(a);
}
```

You can compile it in: https://godbolt.org/z/sysQwj

The error is

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token return a.f<10>();

In instantiation of 'int g(A<N>&) [with int N = 1]':

error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' 
and 'int' to binary 'operator<': return a.f<10>();
```

Comment: `return a.template f<10>();`

Comment: @rafix post the answer for future reader